# PHP Xpath Help, not able to parse the HTML

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to get the 2 values here from below TR codes

1) xyz.com
2) this is great i will give 100 bucks

Below is the HTML code I am trying to Xpath/Parse, however not able to get the desired result.

```
<tr class="something-is-here">
<td>xyz.com</td>
<td class="text-right">
<span>this is great i will give 100 bucks
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Tried below method, however it is not working, it seems.

```
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load($content);
    foreach($html->find('tr') as $myLink) {
        $href = $myLink->span;
if (!is_null($myLink)) {
    foreach ($myLink as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see enough closing curly braces.  Your expression of exactly how your code doesn't work couldn't be more vague/useless.  We wish to see your generated errors (if any) and your incorrect output and if you have narrowed down (via basic diagnostics) the line(s) that are failing please state that.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be :

```
<?php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<tr class="something-is-here">
<td>xyz.com</td>
<td class="text-right">
<span>this is great i will give 100 bucks</span>
</td>
</tr>
XML;
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$elements=$xpath->query('//tr//*[text()[normalize-space()]]');
foreach($elements as $element)
echo $element->nodeValue. "\n";
?>
```

Output :

```
xyz.com
this is great i will give 100 bucks
```

EDIT : Assuming you have HTML :

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$data='<tr class="something-is-here">
<td>xyz.com</td>
<td class="text-right">
<span>this is great i will give 100 bucks
</span>
</td>
</tr>';
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements=$xpath->query('//tr//*[text()[normalize-space()]]');
foreach($elements as $element)
echo $element->nodeValue. "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, However it is not XML, it is HTML Web page I am trying to Parse. Please help.

Comment: XML, HTML, you can parse both with PHP. It will work too. I've edited my answer.